# Serve static files to reverse proxy path nginx

Tags: angularjs, nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to run my application under `myurl.com/app1/` using reserve proxy(nginx) with angularjs. But when I call `myurl.com/app1/` I only get index.html, static files still point to `myurl.com/assets/` rather than `myurl.com/app1/assets/`

```
upstream smileyface {
        server localhost:8081;
}

server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myurl_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myurl_error.log warn;
    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    include snippets/ssl-myurl.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name myurl.com www.myurl.com;

    location /app1/ {
            index index.html;
            alias /angular-app-folder/;
            proxy_pass http://smileyface/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
}
```

Comment: if I put Documentroot in server block, I will be able to grab those static files but I can still access it from [myurl.com](http://myurl.com) which is not what I want

Comment: Can you share the generated `index.html`?